# How to find Logical Name for PinPad XFS if it is not mentioned in Manual

Tags: c++, embedded, registry, xfs, cen-xfs

I have started  `XFS` implementation of SZZT Pinpad .I am facing an issue with the `WFSOpen`  command Its giving an error “ – 14 “which is mentioned as `WFS_ERR_HARDWARE_ERROR` in the Manual. Please let us know if we are missing out on any parameter Value for the same .
Also we are unable to find the logical Name for SZZT Pinpad in the Manual . As of now we are using the same name which is been mentioned in the Registry

Comment: Do you write XFS service provider or simply use existing service provider? If you using existing service provider WFS_ERR_HARDWARE_ERROR means thay is something hardware problems with pinpad, not in WFSOpen call. Logical name may be set to any value. Right value is in registry. You are right.

Comment: I have check the Device through test client it shows OPEN_DEVICE-SUCCESS  that mean there is no issue in the pinpad but as per my code i get hardware error please find screen shot for the same  [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b8725kywghd6p1z/PINPAD-Error.png?dl=0)

Comment: Why you use 0x31 parameter instead of dwSrvcVersionRequired? Which test tool you use? Is it native SZZT tool or some kind of XFS test tool? SZZT tool working with pinpad directly by COM port at low level, XFS service provider for pinpad may require some settings for hardware level.

Comment: @  Alex.D.Alexeev:  I m Using 0x0B020003 this value which is mentioned in Manual for 0x0B020003(2.11 - 3.00)0x0001 0x1402(1.00 - 2.20)`WFS_SUCCESS`0x1402(use 2.20) but i get `WFS_ERR_SERVICE_NOT_FOUND`The logical name is not a valid Service Provider name

Comment: I think there's something wrong with XFS service provider configuration. Can you test XFS pinpad with some kind of XFS tool (from wincor PIN300.exe for example) ?

Answer (score 1):

I've had recently this problem. In my case, it was due to the service provider not being found (more exactly, the SP implementation DLL).
The reason behind, in my case, was that I was using a 64 bits Windows 7. In a 64bits SO, the registry localization  is not in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\XFS but in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\XFS
BTW, the xfs setup puts a 64bitsregs.reg in C:\xfs (or the directory you selected to install the xfs in)

Answer (score 0):

you can find your logical name or service name from below path for windows xp:

general:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\"AtmVendor"\RSPServer\XFS

in my case:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\BanqIT\RSPServer\XFS